# How do you set an environment variable for all users on Fedora?

Tags: fedora

I'm trying to set the ORACLE_HOME environment variable for my nagios daemon user (it's a nologin user).

I've tried adding a script to export the variable in /etc/profile.d/oracle.sh (the execute bits are also set on this file).

This script sets the environment variable for my own user, but not for the nagios daemon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Daemons started via initscripts don't read `profile.d/`. You'll need to make the initscript source a file from `/etc/sysconfig/` that contains the desired value (and then make the `profile.d/` script read it from this as well).

Comment: Thanks Ignacio.  Could you please be more specific on how to make the initscript source a file from /etc/sysconfig/ ? Sorry!

Comment: With the `source` or `.` commands.

Comment: Sorry, do I create a new file in /etc/sysconfig, say called oracle  and then reference this file from an initscript.  I'm not sure where these initscripts live.  do i create a new file somewhere? Thanks for your help!

Comment: are you refering to /etc/init.d/

Comment: Initscripts do live under `/etc/init.d`. One of them starts Nagios, probably called `nagios`. Create a new file in `/etc/sysconfig` with the variable you want to set and source it within the initscript.

Comment: just curious - is it considered poor form to just export the value directly in an init script?  what is the advantage of separating the value out to sysconfig?

Comment: Initscripts are considered code and shouldn't contain values that may change. Also, it's easier to pull it into the user environment if it's separate.