# Setting environment variables for a service without a login shell on Debian

Tags: bash, perl, asterisk

I have created a linux service that runs as a deamon (and gets started from /etc/init.d/X). I need to set some environment variables that can be accessed by the application.

Here's the scenario. The application is a bunch of Perl AGI scripts that depend on (and therefore need to run as) asterisk user but asterisk doesn't have a shell. Ideally I'd just set this in /home/asterisk/.bashrc but that doesn't exist for asterisk.

How can I set environment variables for my app in the asterisk user's running environment so that my app can use them?

**Update**: Changed the title to show am using Debian.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you set an environment variable for all users on Fedora?](http://serverfault.com/questions/179018/how-do-you-set-an-environment-variable-for-all-users-on-fedora)

Comment: Could you tell us what is your OS?

Comment: @Casual: Linux.

Comment: Ok. I was asking domino. Your answer is related to Fedora. Maybe domino is using different distribution where init scripts are not configured in `/etc/sysconfig`

Comment: @Casual - I am using debian. @Ignacio - thanks for the link it helped me know what to look for, for a debian distro. Found the answer and posted it below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. For debian distro creating the file `/etc/default/myservice` 
and then adding the environment variables using the syntax `export VAR=value`

then sourcing the file from `/etc/init.d/myservice` using

`[ -r /etc/default/myservice ] && . /etc/default/myservice` solved the problem